# Number Theory and Inverse Modulo

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Suppose $m$ is a two-digit positive integer such that $6^{-1}\pmod m$ exists and $6^{-1}\equiv 6^2\pmod m$. What is $m$?

I know that the question is asking to compute "m". I have a rough sketch in my mind of what do. However, I'm not fully sure.

I think that there's a number "m", which when multiplied by 6, leaves a remainder of 1 (after being divided by m). That doesn't really make sense though because it would not leave any remainder, Next, I thought that "m", when divided by 6, left a remainder of 1. This, I feel, makes more sense. Then, I thought that when divided by 36, it left a remainder of 1. So I think the answer would be 37 or 73.

Can someone either verify my answer or tell me if I'm completely wrong. If I'm completely wrong, can someone guide me through the answer?

Answer (score 4):

Note that $6^2 \equiv 6^{-1} \pmod m \iff 6^3 \equiv 1 \pmod m \iff m \mid 6^3 - 1 = 215$

But $215 = 43 \cdot 5$, so we must have $m=43$

Answer (score 1):

Multiply by $6$
\begin{eqnarray*}
6^{-1}\equiv 6^2\pmod m \\
6^{3}\equiv 1 \pmod m
\end{eqnarray*}
So $216-1 = k m $ for some integer $k$, $215=5 \times 43$. so $\color{red}{m=43}$.

Answer (score 0):

Guidance:

You have that $6^{-1} \bmod m$ exists, so $\gcd(6,m) =1$ and (by definition) $6\cdot 6^{-1}\equiv 1 \bmod m$.

From this, you can't say much about what $m\bmod 6$ is, except that $m\equiv \{1 \text{ or } 5 \} \bmod 6$ because of the coprime requirement.

Then you have $6^{-1} \equiv 6^2 \bmod m$. We can put that back in the definition of the inverse to get $6\cdot 6^2\equiv 1 \bmod m$, or $216\equiv 1 \bmod m$. And then the solution is simply a matter of finding suitable factors of $215$, as the other answers show.